# PostgreSQL: how do I list the names of the databases?

Tags: postgresql

Simple question. I have access to PostgreSQL. If I knew the name of the database I could

```
psql -d dbname
```

but if I don't know dbname, how can I list what databases are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a valid login:

```
psql -l
```

BTW, this is in the man page.

Comment: thanks. doh, the problem with postgresql is that so many functions are in other instructions, that the obvious never occurred to me